# Visual Studio hangs at Review Solution Actions dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

When trying to open an older C++ project in Visual Studio 2019 Professional, I keep getting this "Review Solution Actions" dialog that hangs Visual Studio.

[image: Dialog]

I've tried starting in safe mode and resetting my user settings but neither of those have done anything.

Once this dialog shows up it just hangs here and I cannot focus on this dialog or Visual Studio. It's as functional as the image of it posted in this question.

I can successfully "End Task" in Task Manager (as opposed to killing the process) so it's still doing something in the Windows message loop (and redrawing)-- but strangely won't obtain focus or allow drags. Haven't seen that before.

Is there a way to retarget this project via the command line? Is there something else I can do?

Version: `VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.5+29806.167`

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2019 Professional are you using? I suggest you could try to install the most recent release from: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. If the problem persists, I suggest you could `Report a problem…`(Help -> Send Feedback)

Comment: `VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.5+29806.167` and `Visual C++ 2019 00435-60000-00000-AA806`. I'll update to 16.5.2. I was hoping there was a command line equivalent of this dialog. Also, it "feels" like there's a hidden/offscreen modal dialog somewhere -- that would explain the focus behavior (though it's missing from the taskbar), as well as why it's still responsive to `WM_CLOSE` via Task Manager. But I cannot find any other window (using Sysinternals tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to `16.5.2` resolved this, thankfully.